# Como fazer uma listbox onde eu possa selecionar mais de um valor?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Desejo fazer uma listbox, onde o usuário possa selecionar várias opções, porém usando o select multiple, eu tenho que segurar ctrl, porém isso não é o ideal, muitas pessoas não vão saber disso. Alguém pode ajudar?

```
<div class="form-group">                
              <label> Dias disponíveis <br />
                <select name="dias" id="dias" multiple>
                  <option value="Segunda-Feira">Segunda-Feira</option>
                  <option value="Terça-Feira">Terça-Feira</option>
                  <option value="Quarta-Feira">Quarta-Feira</option>
                  <option value="Quinta-Feira">Quinta-Feira</option>
                  <option value="Sexta-Feira">Sexta-Feira</option>
                </select>
              </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Existem vários códigos com essa finalidade, porém, nenhum deles funciona em todos os navegadores, o que também não é o ideal. http://jsfiddle.net/xQqbR/1022/  outro http://jsfiddle.net/UziTech/cjjg68dr/114/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Select2](https://select2.org) é um plugin apropriado para isso, caso queiro algo um pouco mais elegante. Basta baixar e colocar o css no header e os arquivos javascript no fim da página, antes do final da tag  `</body>`.

```js
$('.multiplo').select2({
  placeholder: 'selecione'
});
```

```css
.multiplo{
width:50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select class="multiplo" name="" multiple="multiple">
  <option>Um</option>
  <option>Dois</option>
  <option>Três</option>
  <option>Quatro</option>
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/i18n/pt-BR.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.js"></script>
```

Comment: Vlw parceiro, vou tentar dessa forma!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode alterar o comportamento padrão dele, usando apenas Javascript, sem JQuery poderia fazer:

```js
let elemento_options = document.querySelectorAll('select[multiple] option');

elemento_options.forEach(function(elemento, index) {
  elemento.addEventListener("mousedown", option_handler)
});

function option_handler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.selected = !e.target.selected;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label> Dias disponíveis <br>
  <select name="dias" id="dias" multiple>
    <option value="Segunda-Feira">Segunda-Feira</option>
    <option value="Terça-Feira">Terça-Feira</option>
    <option value="Quarta-Feira">Quarta-Feira</option>
    <option value="Quinta-Feira">Quinta-Feira</option>
    <option value="Sexta-Feira">Sexta-Feira</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

Isso irá fazer com que quando clicado (usando `mousedown`, que o mesmo que o navegador usa) vai prevenir o comportamento padrão e vai inverter o valor atual, assim se já estiver marcado vai desmarcar.

Comment: Esse script ele tem que ficar no head né? Ou eu posso deixar ele no body como está ai?